# ReSharper Type Members Layout Pattern - Grouping Event Handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio, resharper

I would like to create a rule to place protected event handler methods in a region using ReSharper. Here are the rules I have, but it's not working.

```
<!-- Event Handlers -->
<Entry>
    <Match>
        <And>
            <Kind Is="method"/>
            <Access Is="protected"/>
            <HandlesEvent/>
        </And>
    </Match>
    <Sort>
        <Name/>
    </Sort>
    <Group Region="Event Handlers"/>
</Entry>
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in ReSharper. I submitted a ticket for it and they will include a fix in a future release. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-275049